# Symbian C++ - Remove or hide component (ie. CEikLabel)

Tags: c++, symbian, carbide

Seemingly a simple enough question, but I cannot work it out.

I want to hide a CEikLabel at a certain point. I want a function like..

```
myLabel->SetVisible(EFalse);
```

or..

```
myLabel->RemoveFromView();
```

I realise I could just use `myLabel->SetTextL(_L(""));` but that is not what I want to do.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about MakeVisible(TBool aVisible);

Also read [about it in Symbian forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=107472)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful answer although so simple.